# Source Code Distribution for clients for an app built with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, encryption, implementation

I have a codeigniter application using mysql and want to install it on clients server, what is the safest way i can do this, i dont want them to copy, modify and distribute the same. Is there a quick and dirty way to do this and then start improving the security the same ? How is this handled in a enterprise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few reason why I wanted to do this in the past:

- To protect the **Implementation**.
- To protect the **Intellectual Property**.

For Implementation reason, we always worry that the client modifies something and produce error/bugs and asks us to fix it. But if the client purchase the software with no right to modify the code, you could always replace the code with the latest build, release, or version. That way, you don't have to deal with bugs that is caused by unauthorized modification.

For Intellectual Property, we usually want to protect the secret 'recipe' or algorithm that we have in those software. We don't want them to duplicate the software for their own and sell them from what we built, and become our competitors. But somehow, I mostly give this up to the client as well. Unless you are distributing proprietary software that belong to principle.

The reason I give this up is, because I believe the assets and values are not ONLY in the software itself, but in the skillful **People** you employ, who design and build it, the **Process** you enforce in your implementation method, and all the **Technology** you use to work with all stakeholders. If the client have a capability to implement the software only from your code base, sooner or later, they'll always find other codes from internet and become your competitors even without using your code base anymore. So it is not as simple as Copy-and-Paste in selling software application that requires implementation.

But if you have other reasons to encrypt your application, you might want to check this site:

- http://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard
- https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption

Cheers,